# Postmark works on local but not staging, mysterious sender signature issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, postmark

This is the error in Heroku's log:

```
2013-06-23T04:57:20.501850+00:00 app[worker.1]: [Worker(host:e681c9a7-c85b-4ca9-af9c-e9bea92be8f0 pid:2)] Class#send failed with Postmark::InvalidMessageError: Sender signature not defined for From address. - 2 failed attempts
```

This is my mailer.

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "postman@writeonpure.com"
  ...
end
```

This is my sender signature defined in Postmark.

[image]

This is application.rb:

```
# Postmark
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :postmark
config.action_mailer.postmark_settings = { :api_key => ENV["POSTMARK_API_KEY"] }
```

Thing is… the mails get sent in development but not in staging.

Comment: Could you please start a Rails console on affected environment and see if `ActionMailer::Base.postmark_settings` returns the same key as when you execute `$ heroku config:get POSTMARK_API_KEY` in your project root?

Answer (score 1):

I has to set `config.mailer_sender` in `config/initializers.devise.rb` to that email address and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have met the same question.  We needed to set `config.mailer_sender` in `config/initializers.devise.rb`, where the `config.mailer_sender` value is the email you had used in the postmark sender signature

Comment: @jonnus, thanks，thank you to help me to correct spelling mistakes, I am  a rookie with English ^_^